Touchpad not detected by Kernel - Debian 12 - ThinkPad E16 Gen2
I've just installed Debian 12 on my ThinkPad E16 Gen 2, and installed using GNOME.
The touchpad doesn't work and it seems that the kernel doesn't register the hardware. This is the xinput list output:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated RGB Camera: Integrat           id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated RGB Camera: Integrat           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]


When checking for modules by running lsmod | grep -E "i2c_hid|psmouse", I get the following:
i2c_hid_acpi           16384  0
psmouse               184320  0
i2c_hid                32768  1 i2c_hid_acpi
hid                   159744  1 i2c_hid

This is my Grub file, in which I added i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.dumbkbd
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.dumbkbd quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

When checking BIOS trackpad is enabled.
In settings->Mouse & Touchpad, there is no settings for touchpad.
I've run sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics.
I've copied 70-synaptics.conf to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
I've updated the kernel in every possible way with sudo apt install linux-image-amd64 as well as using backports.
The log from dmesg | grep touchpad outputs nothing. The same goes for cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | touchpad
I feel like I'm out of options, and the only solutions is to switch to another Linux distributer.
Please help
[SOLVED]
While posting I realized this line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.dumbkbd quiet splash"
was previously written as
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet spla i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.dumbkbd"
with the quiet spla in the beginning, and without the 'h' in splash.
Then it just needed a reboot

welcome to U&L, please do not answer in your question. It is OK to answer one's question. (and you can accept it).

While posting I realized this line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.dumbkbd quiet splash"
was previously written as
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet spla i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.dumbkbd"
with the quiet spla in the beginning, and without the 'h' in splash.
Then it just needed a reboot

The syntax error is relevant, its position as an argument is NOT.
